# Difference between undefined methods and pure virtual methods in a header file

Tags: c++

What are the advantages or disadvantages of using a class declaration with pure virtual methods over using one with undefined members? Example:

---

### Pure virtual functions

**TestClass.h**

```
namespace test {
    class TestClass {
        virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
    }
}
```

**TestClass.cpp**

```
namespace test {
    class TestClassImpl : public TestClass {
        void DoSomething() {
            std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

### Undefined methods

**TestClass.h**

```
namespace test {
    class TestClass {
        void DoSomething();
    }
}
```

**TestClass.cpp**

```
namespace test {
    void TestClass::DoSomething() {
        std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

---

I know that virtual function calls in C++ have an overhead due to indirection and extra branching, but for now these overheads don't concern me. I'm more interested in having extensible, correct code (FYI: I am a C++ newb, but not a programming newb).

Comment: which method is undefined here?

Comment: @RakibulHasan My terminology may be wrong but I meant that DoSomething() is undefined in the header file (then defined in the source file) - sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Also is TestClassImpl meant to inherit from TestClass?

Comment: If the method is defined in the header but defined in the source, then it isn't undefined.

Comment: @LachlanEaston Sorry yes, TestClassImpl should inherit from TestClass - I edited the question to reflect that. Also, what's the right way to name the second approach?

Comment: the second approach might be called "normal code", and your question is "when should a pure virtual function be used"

Comment: An obvious difference between these two cases is that the first one has inheritance and the second one doesn't

Comment: Matt McNabb has it. Without it being virtual you will be unable to override the function in classes that derive from it (if you try then the function will be hidden in non-pointers/non-references). So if you want to be able to override a function, make it virtual. If you want to *force* programmers using your code to override a function (without giving a default) make it pure virtual.

Comment: Why is everything nested in namespaces? Not needed at all for this question.  This link may help you: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They have completely different uses, therefore you should not treat them the same or try to compare them.

---

A pure virtual method means that a derived class must implement that method itself for it to be complete. This will usually be used like this:

**Object.hpp**

```
class Object{
    public:
        virtual void use() = 0;
};

class Banana: public Object{
    public:
        void use(){std::cout << "You ate the Banana! Good work." << std::endl;}
};

class Rock: public Object{
    public:
        void use(){std::cout << "You use the Rock. Nothing happens." << std::endl;}
};
```

So that later on you can refer to instances of `Rock` or `Banana` as `Object`s and know that they will have a `use` function.

E.g.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Object.hpp"

int main(){
    std::vector<Object*> objects;

    Banana banana;
    Rock rock;

    objects.push_back(&banana);
    objects.push_back(&rock);

    for(const Object *o : objects)
        o->use();
}
```

If you decide not to use virtual functions, then you can't treat the objects as `Object`s, per se.

E.g.

**main.cpp**

```
class Banana{
    public:
        void use();
};

class Rock{
    public:
        void use();
};

int main(){
    std::vector<???> objects;

    Banana banana;
    Rock rock;

    objects.push_back(&banana); // can't do
    objects.push_back(&rock); // or this

    for(const ??? *o : objects)
        o->use(); // and definitely not this
}
```

If you try to do this by just delegating your implementations of functions into a different code unit, well, I don't know what you will be trying to do.

You could actually implement your virtual functions in another file, just so long as you do implement them; otherwise when trying to access that kind of object as an `Object` you will get errors.

---

You would want to use functions with outside implementations when dealing with things like libraries and very large projects. You do this so that for every translation of the code you don't have to compile that function again, just call to the already implemented code :D

This makes build times hella shorter.